# ASP.NET MVC - Print out application root

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the path to my application root in an ASP.NET MVC app. I need that path in a dom element I can reach in JavaScript. Currently, I have the following:

```
<link rel="home" id="ApplicationRoot" href="@(~)" />
```

That generates an error that says:

```
 CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
```

I don't know why. Either way, how do I get the application root path put in the `href` value of the `link` element?

Thank you

Comment: try "@Url.Content("~")"

Comment: The `@( ... )` syntax means essentially "treat the bit inside the parentheses as C#/VB code and output whatever the expression returns". Given that, `~` is not even a remotely valid C#/VB expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET MVC helper `@Url.Content`

```
<link rel="home" id="ApplicationRoot" href="@Url.Content("~/")" />
```

or just

```
<link rel="home" id="ApplicationRoot" href="/" />
```